# Access to the system's fonts in WinRT

Tags: c#, fonts, windows-8, windows-runtime

I can not find any information on the topic. I need to read and interpret a font. But I cannot find out how I can read a system font file.

Comment: Are you sure you need to read actual font file or is it possible that you need some font specific information that can be accessed using DirectWrite?

Comment: I do need whole font file in order to interpret it's data

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The **%WINDOWS%\Fonts** directory is not available to Metro style apps.

You can refer to the post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winappswithnativecode/thread/dea8ab00-fa40-48c1-bd1b-19e06e7ac5cd for more information.

Comment: But you can use a Windows Runtime Component. While implementing the component you can use C++ and Win32 and other stuff. Could it be that it is a way to go?

Comment: Were you able to figure out this? I'm in need of a similar task like yours. Any pointers or references I can refer to is fine. So far I had zero luck.